# PrimeFaces autoComplete dropdown not showing values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

After updating from PrimeFaces 8 to 10 all the autoComplete components in my application do not show values when opening the dropdown menu

[image]

The list stays empty. When I debug into AutoComplete and the AutoCompleteRenderer, I can see that the suggestions for an empty query are generated

[image]

But later in the AutoCompleteRenderer the AutoComplete is a new instance (with same component id) without any suggestions.

[image]

This is my JSF page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:autoComplete value="#{testBean.item}"
                        dropdown="true"
                        completeMethod="#{testBean.completeItems}"
                        var="item"
                        itemLabel="#{item}"
                        itemValue="#{iten}" />

        <p:outputLabel value="Selected item: #{testBean.item}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and my bean

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    private String item;

    private final List<String> items = Arrays
            .asList("item-0", "item-1", "item-2", "item-3", "item-4", "item-5", "item-6", "item-7", "item-8", "item-9");

    public List<String> completeItems(final String query) {
        return items.stream()
                .filter(i -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(i, query))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmm I would try and reproduce it using PrimeFaces Test simple reproducer. its possible its a bug but I would be surprised if it was.  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: It is definitely no bug. I could not repeoduce this behaviour with the test project. So I must have done something wrong during the migration from PF 8 to 10. It is a Spring application using PrimeFaces for the frontend. I have updated to JSF 2.3.17 but I am still using the old ManagedBean and ViewScope annotations. They are deprecated I know, but they should still work. I wanted to make this change later.

Comment: Understood yeah I did notice you were using the old annotations.  But glad it works fine in PF Test.

Comment: I found it. javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING was set to false. If I remove this in the web.xml everything works fine. This option was set before I joined the project and I can't find anything explaining why it was set to false.